# How to get the previous element in a SwiftUI ForEach?

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I have a ForEach like this in SwiftUI:

```
ForEach(entries) { (e: MyType) in
   NavigationLinkItem(entry: e)
}
```

now I need to also pass the previous Entry to my View (NavigationLinkItem) to do something like this:

```
ForEach(entries) { (e: MyType) in
   NavigationLinkItem(entry: e, sucessor: ...)
}
```

How to realise that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep `ForEach` dynamic, find below possible approach (assuming `MyType` is `Identifiable`, and successor is optional)

```
ForEach(Array(entries.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, e) in
   NavigationLinkItem(entry: e, sucessor: (index == 0 ? nil : self.entries[index - 1]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this. Assuming you need to pass an object to your successor. I would suggest you make successor an optional

```
ForEach((0...entries.count-1), id:\.self) {i in 
   NavigationLinkItem(entry: self.entries[i], sucessor: i == 0 ? self.entries[0] : self.entries[i-1])
}
```

**EDIT: As suggested in the comments, its better to use indices than count.**

```
ForEach((0...entries.indices), id:\.self) {i in 
   NavigationLinkItem(entry: self.entries[i], sucessor: i == self.entries.startIndex ? self.entries.first : self.entries[i-1])
}
```

Comment: Try `entries.indices` instead of `0...entries.count-1`, and `i == entries.startIndex` instead of `i == 0`. That way it keeps working if you switch to an `ArraySlice` or other `RandomAccessCollection`.

Comment: `self.entries[0]` is also incorrect. It should be `self.entries.first`.